# How can I solve using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL

Tags: cygwin, unwrap

I want to extract DEM from SLC data. But I get this error in Snaphu unwrapping because of Cygwin unmatching. Can anyone tell me any solution please
the error is

snaphu v2.0.4
27 parameters input from file snaphu.conf (84 lines total)
Logging run-time parameters to file snaphu.log
Creating temporary directory snaphu_tiles_2046
0 [main] snaphu (4156) C:\Users\Hi-Tech.snap\auxdata\snaphu-v2.0.4_win64\bin\snaphu.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0xFDB408/0x1BDB408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
1 [main] snaphu 2046 dofork: child -1 - forked process 4156 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
Error while forking
Abort
Process exited with value 2304